# Is there a java convention for packaging enums?

Tags: java, package, conventions

Is there a Java **convention** for packaging enums? if not is there a best practice? 
Should I put them all in one package "myapp.enum" or should I put each enum in its related package?

Comment: Each in its related package. You don't put all your classes in one package "class," right?

Comment: I think this is primarily opinion-based. But anyway, I personally prefer to store an enum within the package it's related to.

Comment: @KonstantinYovkov: Agreed on opinion-based, though I suspect the opinions are almost universally one-sided agreeing with you (and yshavit and Mureinik).

Comment: I am looking for a convention, or eventually a best practice. That's not an opinion.

Comment: If you bring up [the list of all Java SE packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/overview-summary.html), you'll see that there are zero occurrences of separate “enum” or “enums” packages.  That is as close to official convention as you're likely to get.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`enum`s in Java should be treated like any other class, and should probably be placed in the package that's most related to them. There's no advantage in having a separate "enums" package.

Answer (score 11):

`enum` is a reserved keyword so you cannot put your enums into the `enum` package. Packages could be named after the layers of the application (Model, View, Controller, ..) You are free to choose. The only recommendation is to use unique package names like the reverse domain name of your company: `mycompany.com` -> `com.mycompany.myapp`...

Comment: Thanks for the reserved name remark, I edited my question.

Comment: @sabrina2020 this won't work either `myapp.enum`